# Show that all diagonal and off-diagonal entries of a matrix are same

Tags: matrices, idempotents

If $\theta>0$ and $C_{n\times n}$ is a symmetric matrix of rank $n-1$ (with $\vec{\mathbf 1}$ as the only vector in kernel) such that
$$\theta C^2=C$$
How to show that all the diagonal entries of $C$ are equal and so offdiagonal entries of $C$ are also equal?

**My attempts:** I tried to show that $C=aI+b\mathbf 1\mathbf1'$ for some numbers $a$ and $b$ but failed. Also tried to show that $e_i'Ce_i=e_j'Ce_j$ for all $i$ and $j$, but couldn't prove why $||Ce_i||=||Ce_j||$ (where $e_i$ is the canonical basis vector). Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints.** Since $C$ is symmetric and $\mathbf1$ is an eigenvector of $C$ corresponding to the zero eigenvalue, $C$ has an orthonormal eigenbasis $\{u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n\}$ such that $u_1=\mathbf1/\sqrt{n}$ and $C=\sum_{i\ge2}\lambda_iu_iu_i^T$. Apply the condition $\theta C^2=C$ to relate $\theta$ to $\lambda_i$ for each $i\color{red}{\ge2}$. Hence use the equality $I=\sum_{i\color{red}{=1}}^nu_iu_i^T$ to show that $C=aI+b\mathbf1\mathbf1^T$ for some $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Using $C=\sum_{i\ge2}\lambda_iu_iu_i^T$ in $\theta C^2=C$, I am getting $\theta\lambda_i^2=\lambda_i\:\forall\:i\ge2$. How to go ahead?

Comment: @Martund Express $\lambda_i$ in terms of $\theta$.

Comment: So $a=\frac1\theta$ and $b=-\frac1{\theta n}$, right?

Comment: @Martund Yes, that's correct.